# Multiple Arguments in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Very new to coding in excel and mostly follow tutorials to help with my workplace.

Building a multiple entry tracker for data collection, where it transfers the data from one workbook to another workbook "database".

Anyways, one part of my tracker uses radio buttons, and my business wants to introduce a 3rd radio button.

Roadblock:
Currently using an IIF function:

```
.Range("C" & iRow).Value = IIf(frmDataEntry.optDCH.Value = True, "Discharge" , "Funding")
```

Question:
HWhat would be the code to expand this into 3 options and introduce an "Other" category so that if the user does not pick either Discharge or Funding it selects Other?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just check the value of each option button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested IIf statements in this way

```
.Range("C" & iRow).Value = IIf(frmDataEntry.optDCH.Value = True, "Discharge", _
                           IIf(frmDataEntry.optFND.Value = True, "Funding", _
                           "Other"))
```

You can also you a switch statement

```
.Range("C" & iRow).Value = Switch(frmDataEntry.optDCH.Value = True, "Discharge", _
                                  frmDataEntry.optFND.Value = True, "Funding", _
                                  True, "Other")
```

Comment: nested IIf statement worked! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```vb
Dim v

Select Case True
    Case frmDataEntry.optDCH.Value: v = "Discharge"
    Case frmDataEntry.optFund.Value: v = "Funding" 'guessing at the control name...
    Case Else: v = "Other"
End Select

.Range("C" & iRow).Value = v
```

If this code is in the userform you can use `Me` instead of `frmDataEntry`